# WordPress Admin Email

Tags: admin

I am planning to build a WordPress site in which I will setup WooCommerce to sell products. I have created a test site before in which I used my personal email account (gmail) as admin email. Then I tested selling from the site. The problem I faced is that the order confirmation emails were going to spam folder of test client email. And the reason of marking as spam is that The message may not have been sent by ____@gmail.com.

How can I prevent the problem in my actual site? Should I start off with an email address such as ____@myactualsite.com ? Or can I start with my personal email address as the admin email and then later change the admin email? Or can I just use my personal email as admin email and in the WooCommerce email setting I should enter sales@myactualsite.com.

To those who have already built and running WooCommerce sites, What is the best possible option regarding using emails?

Any suggestion will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend to use the domain of the website as the email address. It's look more professional and formal. You can use no-reply email for sent messages related to the shop as sales@example.com and for the main email address I would recommend to use contact@example.com.

You always can change the email address that you entered and test it but if the website is going to be active, better to chose one email address from the start.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid message being sent to spam, you can use a transactional email service (two with free plans are mailgun and mandrillapp). You can use the smtp settings they provide with the postman-smtp plugin (https://wordpress.org/plugins/postman-smtp/). Be sure to configure the DNS settings for better deliverability.

I would prefer not to use no-replay emails. Today is very easy to configure any email address and to let people be able to reply to that address. Is always nice if customers can just reply to the email they receive.

A nice way is to use a kind of personal email, like john@yourdomain.com, this gives people the impression that they are relating with a person and that you are open to talk to them when they need it. People will always appreciate that.

If you are a small business and you are the person that is going to handle the email, you can configure that email address to forward to your gmail account, then configure gmail to let you reply from that address, so you can handle all email written to that email or any other in your domain directly inside gmail.